# Java: Заполнить двухмерные массивы с случайными числами разных диапозонов

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа, повторы

Нужно заполнить двухмерный массив со случайными числами. При этом на каждый столб, должен быть свой диапазон и числа не должны повторяться. Импорт и создание отдельных классов не допускается.

Часть кода пока что выглядит вот так:

```java
int[][] c = new int[5][5];

for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < c[i].length; j++) {

        double x = (Math.random() * 15 * (j + 1) + 1);
        int a = (int) x;

        do {
            a = (int) (Math.random() * 15 * (j + 1) + 1);
            break;
        } while (a == c[i][j]);
```

Проблема в том, что цифры всё ещё повторяются. Мне кажется, что ошибка в диапазоне. Диапазон должен быть для первого столба 1-15, для второго 16-30 и так далее. Я пробовала уже по-разному его ограничить, но всегда выходят не подходящее числа (либо негативные, либо за рамками диапазона). Не знаю, как это можно исправить и в чем на самом деле ошибка. :/
Надеюсь мне кто-нибудь сможет посоветовать, что делать далее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал более лаконичное решение. Так как у нас уникальность в разрезе колонок уже есть то стоит проверить лишь одну колонку а не все числа массива

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array_length = 5; // Количество элементов массива
        int rand_step = 15; // разница между минимумом и максимум для каждой колонки
        int array_min, array_max, numb;
        boolean in_array = true;
        int[][] twoDimArray = new int[array_length][array_length];
        for(int i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < array_length; j++) {
                // рандж для гпсч от и до для каждой колонки
                array_max = rand_step * (j + 1);
                array_min = array_max - rand_step;
                do {
                    in_array = false;
                    // создаём случайное число
                    numb = (int) (Math.random() * ((array_max - array_min) + 1)) + array_min;
                    // проверим на уникальность
                    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                        if ((int) twoDimArray[k][j] == (int) numb) {
                            in_array = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } while(in_array);
                twoDimArray[i][j] = numb;
                System.out.print(numb);
                System.out.print("\t"); //print tab
            }
            System.out.print("\r\n"); // print new line
        }
    }
}
```

результаты: [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk2XBvEjS)

Answer (score 2):

Создаем двумерный массив `int[5][5]` и заполняем каждую строку случайными неповторяющимися начениями из различных диапазонов:

```java
int dimension = 5;

int[][] arr = IntStream.range(0, dimension)
        .mapToObj(i -> {
            HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            while (set.size() < dimension) {
                set.add(10 + i * 10 + (int) (Math.random() * 10));
            }
            return set.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
        })
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [17, 10, 11, 12, 13]
// [20, 21, 22, 26, 29]
// [32, 33, 36, 38, 30]
// [40, 42, 43, 45, 46]
// [53, 54, 56, 57, 58]
```

Транспонирование матрицы, на всякий случай:

```java
IntStream.range(0, 44)
        .filter(i -> i % 10 < 5)
        .filter(i -> i / 10 > i % 10)
        .forEach(i -> {
            int temp = arr[i / 10][i % 10];
            arr[i / 10][i % 10] = arr[i % 10][i / 10];
            arr[i % 10][i / 10] = temp;
        });

Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [17, 20, 32, 40, 53]
// [10, 21, 33, 42, 54]
// [11, 22, 36, 43, 56]
// [12, 26, 38, 45, 57]
// [13, 29, 30, 46, 58]
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, столбцы получились частично упорядоченными, и это не совпадение. Здесь больше подойдет `LinkedHashSet`. И запрет на использование сторонних классов скорее всего распространяется и на стримы и на сеты.